# Generic Dynamic Array not updating properties correctly

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I am creating a generic dynamic array in C. Whenever I update any value in the array, it doesn't update properly and seems to be updating everything in the array. The output of my main file is not expected. I am having trouble finding what the error is in gdb.

My header file:

```
#ifndef INC_6_VECTOR_H
#define INC_6_VECTOR_H
typedef struct Vector_S * Vector;

Vector init_Vector();
void free_Vector(Vector);
void vector_add(Vector, int, void *);
void * vector_value(Vector, int);

#endif //INC_6_VECTOR_H
```

My Source File:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Vector.h"

#define STARTINGSIZE 10

struct Vector_S{
    void **head;
    size_t size;
    size_t length;
};

Vector init_Vector(){
    Vector vector = malloc(sizeof(struct Vector_S));
    vector->size = 0;
    vector->length = STARTINGSIZE;
    vector->head = malloc(STARTINGSIZE * sizeof(void *));
    return vector;
}

void free_Vector(Vector vector){
    free(vector->head);
    free(vector);
}
void vector_add(Vector vector, int idx, void * data){
    if (vector->size >= vector->length){
        size_t oldLength = vector->length;
        void *headTemp;
        headTemp = realloc(vector->head, 2*oldLength* sizeof(void *));
        if (headTemp == NULL){
            printf("Failed realloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        vector->length = 2*oldLength;
        vector->head = headTemp;
    }
    vector->head[idx] = data;
    vector->size++;

}
void * vector_value(Vector vector, int idx){
    return vector->head[idx];
}
```

and my testing file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Vector.h"
int main(void){
    printf("Main run test\n");
    Vector v = init_Vector();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vector_add(v, 0, (void *)&i);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("The value at %d idx is %d\n", i, *(int*)vector_value(v,i));
    }
}
```

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: I wanted to use Vector as a pointer because I just wanted this to be a generic library class I can use without worrying about the internal representation. Was this not the appropriate idea?

Comment: That makes sense, its just a pointer to type for hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store pointers in your vector and not values. In the loop

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    vector_add(v, 0, (void *)&i);
}
```

you store 10 times the address of the same `i` variable.

Change the design if you want to store values instead.

Comment: Thanks for this, i didn't realize I was referencing the same i variable.